# Passing props in React from one file to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below code I want to pass name from Person.js to App.js as prop.But I can't understand how to do it.If you can please explain me how to do that.

**App.js**

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
// import Person from './Person'

function App(props) {
  const [greet, setGreeet] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> Good {greet} </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Person.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App'

export default function Person (){
    const name="Jenifer"
    return(
        <div></div>
    );
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Hello, why don't you just set the name as a local state directly in the App component? 'Cause right now I can't figure out the reason why you create the Person component

Comment: The react docs are a great place to start if you don't quite understand how react state and props work and how data flows through a react app. https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html I still refer back to the react docs almost daily.

Comment: Could you show how App and Person are supposed to work together?

Comment: I suspect by your code snippet you are trying to pass data from child to parent. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason for this.This happened because I tried to pass data from my child class to parent class.It is impossible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> *passing name as prop from person.js(Parent Component) to App.js(Child Component)*

**Person.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App'

export default function Person (){
    const name="Jenifer"
    return(
        <div>
        <App name={name}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**App.js**

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
// import Person from './Person'


function App(props) {
const [greet, setGreeet] = useState("");



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> Good Morning {props.name} </h1> // Good Morning Jenifer
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

checkout this blog post [Passing props between components](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for how to pass data from child to parent.

You have to pass a method from App to Person.

And call the method from Person component.

Also please see the docs

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

```
function Person (props){
  const {setNameToApp} = props;
  const name = "Jennifer"; 
  
// this useEffect is called when the component mounts for the first time
 React.useEffect(()=>{
   setNameToApp(name);
 },[])
  
// I have also shown how to use button to change the greet state in the app.

  return (
<div>
 <button onClick={()=>{setNameToApp("name when I pressbutton")}}> Set Name </button> 
</div>)
}

function App(props) {
  const [greet, setGreet] = React.useState("");
 
// pass setGreet function to components which can call this and change the state of the greet
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Good  {greet} </h1>
      <Person  setNameToApp = {setGreet} /> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why not just `setNameToApp={setGreet}` and save the proxy function? :)

Comment: True, but just wanted to show how the functions are passed between components :)

Comment: `setGreet` ***is*** a function, passed between components. ;)

Comment: Hahah, agreed! Done. Trying to come up with a reason I couldn't lol.

Comment: @DrewReese Got a quick question, is callback created each time the functional component renders? Is that why setGreet directly is better than the proxy function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64547776/react-performance-issues-in-passing-callback-as-props-in-functional-components I have posted a question regarding this. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, `arg => setGreet(arg)` will create an anonymous function every render, but this is constant time `O(1)` overhead. CertainPerformance answered it well enough. I would strive for less anonymous functions where possible, but only reach for a memoized callback if you *actually* start seeing performance issues with callbacks passed to children.